# how to select all checkbox inside td

Tags: javascript, html

i'm just learned the javascript. i'm trying to make a simple front-end for practice. so, i've been struggling to select all checkbox inside 'td'.

```
<table>
  <tr class="top1000">
     <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="ropangTopping()"><label>milo</label></td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="ropangTopping()"><label>chocolate</label></td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="ropangTopping()"><label>chocochip</label></td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="ropangTopping()"><label>koko krunch</label></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="top3000">
      <td><input type="checkbox"  onclick="ropangTopping()"><label>mozarella</label></td>
       <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="ropangTopping()"><label>cheddar</label></td>
       <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="ropangTopping()"><label>green tea</label></td>
       <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="ropangTopping()"><label>boba</label></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

when i initialized with this `var topping1000 = document.querySelector(".top1000 td input[type=checkbox]");`, it just select the first checkbox. but when i use `querySelectorAll` it didn't select anything. i know this is a silly question. any answer would be appriciated it. thanks in advance.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` will work and which returns NodeList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. You *do* need to use

```
querySelectorAll()
```

to grab *all* the nodes.

But *then* you need to loop through those nodes and check each one in turn.

One way to do this (there are several) might be to use a `forEach` loop:

```
toppings1000.forEach((topping1000) => {topping1000.checked = true;});
```

---

**N.B.** Note the *names* of the variables I'm using immediately above. I'm distinguishing between the collection of multiple nodes (`toppings1000`):

```
toppings1000 // with an 's' to indicate that it's a plural set
```

and the individual node in each iteration of the `forEach` loop (`topping1000`):

```
topping1000 // no 's' this time - it's just a single node
```

---

**Working Example:**

```js
var toppings1000 = document.querySelectorAll(".top1000 td input[type=checkbox]");

toppings1000.forEach((topping1000) => {

  topping1000.checked = true;

});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="top1000">
     <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="ropangTopping()"><label>milo</label></td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="ropangTopping()"><label>chocolate</label></td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="ropangTopping()"><label>chocochip</label></td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="ropangTopping()"><label>koko krunch</label></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="top3000">
      <td><input type="checkbox"  onclick="ropangTopping()"><label>mozarella</label></td>
       <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="ropangTopping()"><label>cheddar</label></td>
       <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="ropangTopping()"><label>green tea</label></td>
       <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="ropangTopping()"><label>boba</label></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You'll find it's a quite a common pattern to grab a collection of nodes from the DOM and then to loop through each member of the collection, adding to it or altering it in some way. The example above uses a `forEach()` loop, but ES2015+ introduces a `for...of` loop which is just as easy to use: `for (topping1000 of toppings1000) {topping1000.checked = true;}`.